# Как вывести статические страницы в Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

В теме Wordpress есть меню, в котором должны быть ссылки на статичные страницы. Как правильно проставить эти ссылки и вывести эти страницы? У каждой страницы разный шаблон. Заранее благодарен!

Comment: Создайте пустые страницы в админке, назначьте им шаблоны.

Comment: А как им присвоить шаблоны?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Допустим, у вас есть шаблон страницы `/sun`. Берите этот файл, называйте его `page-sun.php` и кладите в корневую папку вашей темы.

Заголовок файла должен быть таким:

```
<?php
// дальше ваш код php или чистый html...
```

Создайте в админке пустую страницу sun с ярлыком sun. Сохраните.

Теперь при обращении по адресу `http://ваш-сайт.org/sun` будет срабатывать ваш шаблон `page-sun.php`.

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: Если ответ полезен, его стоит отметить как принятый галочкой внизу. Это поможет ориентироваться пользователям, которые ищут ответ на подобный вопрос.